# Jqgrid edit row auto-resize option

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Do we have a auto-resizing option for jqgrid edit mode. I use edit cell and say if the user has large text then, on double click it enters the edit mode, its likely that user cant read the text because that looks like text field is of fixed length. Is there a way we can resize it so that user can see the entire content/text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are finding inline edit too restrictive, you might want to consider opening a dialog to edit a row instead. For example, the dialog could have plenty of space for your large text field.